# Unable to import more than 110 Columns in single table in NDBC

Tags: ndbcluster

I have configured NDBCLUSTER with 4 data nodes, 1 sql node and 1 management node. But I have increased the 4GB of DataMemory size for every node and IndexMemory size 500MB also. I have given MaxNoOfAttributes=2000 in every node. I have increased  the page size for every node.
But the problem is I am unable to create more than 110 columns in a table in ndbcluster.

Answer (score 0):

For NDB the maximum row size is 30000 bytes.

A common source of bigger columns than expected is VARCHAR or CHAR columns, the default character set is UTF-8 (utf8mb4) which will require 4 bytes per character and that the VARCHAR columns takes as much space when calculating row size as if they were filled up to its maximum.

BLOB, TEXT, JSON columns are special that only a so called inline part is stored in the main row and the rest in separate hidden tables.  The inline part is typically 256 bytes but can be changed by using the column option BLOB_INLINE_SIZE.

References: